# JavaFX2: Drag Event start and end coordinates

Tags: javafx-2, mouseevent, drag

I have one node(ImageView) that displays an image and another node(rectangle) that resides on top of it. The behavior I need is that when the mouse is dragged(press-drag-release gesture) over the rectangle, both the nodes should move coherently. My thought process goes in the following direction:

•   Move both the nodes by the same distance in the direction of the drag.

For this option(maybe there are more options) I need the distance between the start and end of the mouse drags. I tried capturing the start and end coordinates of the drag but have been unsuccessful. I think I am getting lost in which handlers to implement.

The code I have is below:

```
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

public class MyView
{

    double    mouseDragStartX;
    double    mouseDragEndX;

    double    mouseDragStartY;
    double    mouseDragEndY;

    ImageView imageView;

    public MyView()
    {
        imageView = new ImageView("C:\\temp\\test.png");
    }

    private void setRectangleEvents(final MyObject myObject)
    {
        myObject.getRectangle().setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent)
            {
                mouseDragStartX = mouseEvent.getX();
                mouseDragStartY = mouseEvent.getY();
                mouseEvent.consume();
            }
        });

        myObject.getRectangle().setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
        {
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent)
            {
                mouseDragEndX = mouseEvent.getX();
                mouseDragEndY = mouseEvent.getY();
                myObjectDraggedHandler();
            }
        });
    }

    private void myObjectDraggedHandler()
    {

    Rectangle2D viewport = this.imageView.getViewport();
    double newX = this.imageView.getImage().getWidth()
        + (mouseDragEndX - mouseDragStartX);
    double newY = this.imageView.getImage().getHeight()
        + (mouseDragEndY - mouseDragStartY);

        this.imageView.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(newX, newY, viewport.getWidth(),     viewport
            .getHeight()));

    }
}
```

P.S: This code is just for indicating what I am trying to implement and will not compile correctly.

Or maybe my question should just have been:
How to capture the length or span of a mouse drag?

Answer (score 3):

try this i think it would help you

```
obj.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
  @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    // record a delta distance for the drag and drop operation.
    dragDelta.x = stage.getX() - mouseEvent.getScreenX();
    dragDelta.y = stage.getY() - mouseEvent.getScreenY();
  }
});
obj.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
  @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
      stage.setX(mouseEvent.getScreenX() + dragDelta.x);
    stage.setY(mouseEvent.getScreenY() + dragDelta.y);
  }
});
```